# Embed work items (local Azure DevOps server) on SharePoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, site, azure, sharepoint-integration

We use a local Azure DevOps server (version Dev17.M153.3) and use SharePoint Online (Office 365). The following should be possible:

- As a user, I want to be able to **embed a list of work items** on a
  SharePoint website. This list can be a **backlog**, a **sprint backlog** or
  the **result of a query**.
- As a user I want to be able to link from an SharePoint site to a work element in TFS as easily as possible.
- As a user, I want to be able to link from a work element in TFS to a
  SharePoint site as easily as possible.

I found out that a SharePoint Azure DevOps Server integration no longer exists. I looked at all articles from Microsoft about this. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to implement the above - the first point is the most important and so far it seems that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your DevOps server is behind a firewall, and your SharePoint is in the cloud, so first you'll have to figure out whether or not you want to expose your DevOps data outside the network.

Here's what I would do:

1. Flow has DevOps connectors. Find out if they extend to on-premises environments and connect to them using a Data Gateway.
2. If #1 is not possible, deploy a custom API that pulls data from DevOps via its APIs, and connect to that from SharePoint.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/visualstudioteamservices/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/flow/gateway-reference

Comment: Hi @derek thanks, but if I work with Flow, I have only trigger and actions. I could create a nice automated workflow, but that's not what I want to achieve. I want to give users the opportunity to place one workitem or a selection of workitems on a wiki page.